# What is the benefit of never in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have just started with typescript and read about the type **never**. But I did not get the actual purpose of it. From [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/18/typescript-2-0-the-never-type)

I got, any code that is not going to execute or unreachable is marked as never

```
// Type () => never
const sing = function() {
    while (true) {
        console.log("Never gonna give you up");
        console.log("Never gonna let you down");
        console.log("Never gonna run around and desert you");
        console.log("Never gonna make you cry");
        console.log("Never gonna say goodbye");
        console.log("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
    }
};
```

The function in above code has an infinite loop so that will be marked as never, so what is the benefit of this?

Comment: *"any code that is not going to execute or unreachable is marked as never"* – no. All the code in the example you've given is going to execute. The return value of any function that *doesn't ever return* is "never".

Comment: There's a good description of how you might use `never` in Typescript Deep Drive https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/never.html

Comment: @JJJ , if the above code is going to execute then how the value could be returned as the function will get stuck in loop?

Comment: ...what? I specifically said that it **doesn't** return anything.

Comment: if this will not return anything that is code cant process further and will stuck here forever, then what is the benefit of making return type never? i am confused?

Comment: What should its return type be then?

Comment: data type will matter if i will handle this situation something that will break the loop otherwise app is in crashed state.

Comment: Thank you for the humor in your question. Made my day!

Comment: glad this made your day!! :) but humor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some use cases of "Never" keyword in Typescript.

The never type is used when you are sure that something is never going to occur.

✅ Guard Clauses: it forces you to check all possible cases.

✅ Function will never return anything. It has something to do all the time (infinitive loop)

✅ Function always Throws Error.

```
// 1) Guard Clauses (forces you to check all possible cases)
type CurrencyOptions = "EURO" | "USD" | "AZN"

    function getRate(currency: CurrencyOptions) {
    switch (currency) {
        case "EURO":
            return 1.80
        case "USD":
            return 1.70
        case "AZN":
            return 1.20
        default:
            const _unreachable: never = currency  // will get Type Error if you remove one of the cases 
            throw "Not found"
    }
}



// 2) function will Throw error

function throwError(errorMsg: string): void {
    throw new Error(errorMsg);
}



// 3) function will Never end
function keepProcessing(): never {
    while (true) console.log('Never ends.')
}
```

Main difference between **never** and **void** is that:

**Void** - function doesn't return anything or explicitly returns undefined.

**Never** - function never returns anything at all.

Answer (score 7):

For your example, the benefit is to guarantee that you wont create a escape from your function.

Try to explicitly set the `never` return type.

```
const sing = function():never {
    while (true) {
        console.log("Never gonna give you up");
        console.log("Never gonna let you down");
        console.log("Never gonna run around and desert you");
        console.log("Never gonna make you cry");
        console.log("Never gonna say goodbye");
        console.log("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");

        break; // Error
    }
};
```